# How to manually assign communities and measure modularity?

Tags: r, igraph, modularity

I have a network for which I would like to compare the modularity scores that are derived from various algorithms, e.g. walktrap, with the modularity scores that are derived by community membership of my own choosing (assigned by hand).  For example, I would like to be able to assign every node a "commmunity" of 1 or 2.  So far, I have used various means to try to achieve this and they typically crash the R environment when I run modularity(graph1, assigned_communities).

```
library(igraph)
raw1 <- read.csv("C:\\edge list directed weighted.csv")
graph1 <- graph.data.frame(raw1, directed=TRUE, vertices=NULL)

attrib <- read.csv("C:\\vertex_groups.csv")
```

"attrib" is the object holding my assigned groups.  The .csv file contains four columns - "vertex" which is the sorted list of unique vertices contained in graph1, and other columns with the communities I would like to be able to assign to those vertices, in this example "group1" "group2" etc.

```
##method1: communities object type clone
members <- as.double(attrib$group1)
nam <- as.character(attrib$vertex)
comms <- list(membership=members, vcount=vcount(graph1), names=nam, algorithm="by.hand")
class(comms) <- "communities"
modularity(graph1, membership(comms) )
```

This first attempt is to clone a "communities" object.  I extract the column from the attrib object corresponding to group1, the group i want to assign as a community.  Running that modularity command crashes the environment.

```
v = attrib$group1
names(v) = attrib$vertex
modularity(graph1,v)
```

Here, v extracts the group1 values as a column but also names the rows to match the style of a commmunity object.  This also crashes the environment.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The crashing was caused by running this code on 64 bit R, I changed to 32 bit and the crashing stopped.  Go figure.